# Maintaining links using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fix the code of an existing site. The navigation we're using hashes to associate to a content id. All content is hidden, on click the id matching the nav hash in the anchor tag will display the appropriate content with the ID.

The problem I'm having is that one particular piece of navigation has a sub section, I need one link to  link out to a PDF while maintaining the parents page content. Currently though, it'll either maintain the page content OR link out to PDF. Curious on how you all might solve for this kind of situation.

[You can see the page live](http://pbj.me/dev/enk/acic/)

Here is the section I'm talking about:

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#floor-plan">Floor Plans</a>
   <ul class="sub-nav">
     <li><a href="#floor-plan">3D Map</a></li>
     <li><a href="../link/to/pdf">Detailed Floorplan</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
$(".main--nav").each(function(){
    $('.main--nav li a').on('click', function(){
     // e.preventDefault();
     var $id = $(this).attr('href');
     $('.exhib-content').hide();
     $($id).show();
    });
});
```

NOTE: I commented out 'preventDefault();' for testing, as it wouldn't let the link actually kick out to the PDF, or anything for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target only href's starting with `#` using [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), also where is no need for the each loop

```
$('.main--nav li a[href^="#"]').on('click', function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $id = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.exhib-content').hide();
    $($id).show();
});
```